# Adding field delimiter ";" in last column on header file

Tags: datastage

I'm new in datastage and trying to create a sequential file with ";" as delimeter.
I would like to add my delimeter just after the last column in the headers

please see below exemple for more understanding

Actully i have this in my sequential file :

SERVICE_ID;OFFER_ID;MINIMUM;MAXIMUM

19441;162887;;;

19442;162889;;;

Expected result with delimiter after last column in header :

SERVICE_ID;OFFER_ID;MINIMUM;MAXIMUM;

19441;162887;;;

19442;162889;;;

How can i do that please ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Final Delimiter property in the Sequential File stage format properties.